# Failure to load lwjgl

Tags: java, lwjgl

I finished setting up lwjgl and tried to run the example from the website, but then, I keep getting this error (I changed the name of the class):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to load       the native library: lwjgl32
at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.loadLibrarySystem(LWJGLUtil.java:338)
at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:36)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:33)
at mehavenowebsite.DoStuff.run(DoStuff.java:24)
at mehavenowebsite.DoStuff.main(DoStuff.java:114)
```

I set up lwjgl correctly, and I added the natives, so I have no idea what's going on. I am using eclipse luna, with lwjgl 3. Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks.

EDIT: code:

```
package mehavenowebsite;

import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class DoStuff {

// We need to strongly reference callback instances.
private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;
private GLFWKeyCallback   keyCallback;

// The window handle
private long window;

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Sys.getVersion() + "!");

    try {
        init();
        loop();

        // Release window and window callbacks
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        keyCallback.release();
    } finally {
        // Terminate GLFW and release the GLFWerrorfun
        glfwTerminate();
        errorCallback.release();
    }
}

private void init() {
    // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
    // will print the error message in System.err.
    glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = errorCallbackPrint(System.err));

    // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
    if ( glfwInit() != GL11.GL_TRUE )
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

    // Configure our window
    glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

    int WIDTH = 300;
    int HEIGHT = 300;

    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
    if ( window == NULL )
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

    // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
            if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE); // We will detect this in our rendering loop
        }
    });

    // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
    ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    // Center our window
    glfwSetWindowPos(
        window,
        (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - WIDTH) / 2,
        (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - HEIGHT) / 2
    );

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Make the window visible
    glfwShowWindow(window);
}

private void loop() {
    // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
    // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
    // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
    // creates the ContextCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
    // bindings available for use.
    GLContext.createFromCurrent();

    // Set the clear color
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
    // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
    while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE ) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

        // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
        // invoked during this call.
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DoStuff().run();
}

}
```

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkError means the natives couldn't be loaded. How did you add them?

Comment: In eclipse: Window->Preferences->Java->Build Path->User Libraries->lwjgl32->lwjgl.jar->Native Library Location->Edit

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the library the "Eclipse way"?

**Step 1**

[image: Step 1]
**Step 2**

[image: Step 2]

**Step 3**
[image: Step 3]

**Step 4**
[image: Step 4]

**Step 5**
[image: Step 5]

**Step 6**
[image: Step 6]

**Step 7**
[image: Step 7]

Comment: I tried it like that and it still didn't work. But thanks anyway.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://github.com/SilverTiger/lwjgl3-tutorial/wiki/Setup) says the following about the error: "_If you get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to load the native library: lwjgl you have not set the org.lwjgl.librarypath correctly. This is the most important part when setting up your project, so make sure you have set the native path to the right folder._" Are you sure you selected the proper native library path? Make sure you select the Native library location as a folder.